# How do I convert all accounts on a dovecot IMAP server from one Maildir layout to another?

Tags: email, migration, dovecot, maildir

I am currently running dovecot 2.x on a server with the following layout for mailboxes:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

I would like to change the layout to this format:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir:LAYOUT=fs:INBOX=~/Maildir/INBOX
```

Is there a way to convert the mailbox layout for all mail accounts currently on the server? I was looking at dsync, but all examples in Dovecot's wiki are for converting between mbox and Maildir.

I was also looking at potentially writing a script to manually rename directories/move files around to match the new format, but wasn't sure whether that would mess with UIDs or other dovecot internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not need to change anything *inside* each Maildir directory (i.e. inside the folder that contains the `cur`, `new`, `tmp` directories and the dovecot indices), moving the directories around with a script will be perfectly safe, and quite sufficient.

The only exception to this is for INBOX itself, because you have it directly in `~/Maildir` now and you would like to move it to a subdirectory. But even then, I think that a script that is careful about what files it moves and which ones it doesn't is the best way to go. If you move every plain file from `~/Maildir` to `~/Maildir/INBOX` (covers all Dovecot index files) plus `cur`, `new`, `tmp` (covers the contents themselves) and leave all other subdirectories alone (covers other folders) then I think that should do the trick.